# All-on-one-page print view in Plone

Tags: printing, plone

We have a Plone 4 document that is in a hierarchy.  At each node there's either a document, or a folder.  Folders then have more documents and folders.  We want to be able to print the entire hierarchy, which means rendering the whole thing on one page.

I see a number of web sites like [this one](http://www.bikalabs.com/helpcentre/manual/bika-installation-guides/bika-on-ubuntu-linux/referencemanual-all-pages) that seem to have something like this.  Is it manually done or is there some add-on I can get to make this feature possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's manually done....